# Counting list items and storing in dataframe column corresponding to list item

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, counter

I am trying to iterate over a Series in a Pandas Dataframe and storing the count of list items in another column with the same name as the item for every row. The series is like a list of lists so basically I'm trying to convert that list of lists to a one-hot vector but each item in this vector is a column. There are finite number of items that can appear.

Following is my approach. It works fine, but its hella slow. I am posting this here to try and find a better, more "pythonic", way to do this.

```
N_Series = len(df.Category)
for i in range(N_Series):
    itemList = df.Category[i]
    N_List = len(itemList)
    for k,v in Counter(itemList).items():
         df[k][i] = v/N_List
```

Following is an example, The Category column is a list and the corresponding one-hot columns can be seen holding the count of item/number of items in list.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add some example input/output? Thanks

Comment: I do not think `df[k][i] = v/N_List` will work

Comment: @FrancisWebb Thanks for requesting this edit. Hope this helps.

Comment: @YOBEN_S Interesting. It worked just fine for me. Why do you think it wont work?

Comment: Please include sample input, as well as the expected output, **as text** in your question so others can easily reproduce it.

Comment: @Roy2012 Im actually reading this data from a file. Could you elaborate on including sample input in the question as text? The sample input can be any object of pd.Series (as the Category column in the photo above) and the sample output is attached as an image.

Comment: Now it is clear `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `explode` + `corsstab`

```
s=df.Category.explode()
s=pd.crosstab(s.index,s,normalize='index')
df=df.join(s)
```

Comment: Why does normalize=True give weird values? In other words, what does it return when normalize is True when, for example, 1 is sent.

Comment: How do I get the distribution of each item instead of normalized value?

Comment: @SambbhavGarg change to `pd.crosstab(s.index,s,normalize='index')`